# How to modify a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key

I want to add on to my current dictionary without hardcoding. I want to distinguish between stores by adding -A and based on the station someone is working in.

```
a_dict = {'A': [['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']],'B': [['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]}
b_dict = {'Site':"", 'Store':"", 'Station':""}
for key in a_dict:
    b_dict.update(a_dict) 
    print(b_dict[key[0]])
```

This is what the code currently prints out

```
[['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']]
[['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]
```

But I want it to print out this

```
[['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves-A']]
[['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves-A']]
```

Comment: There is no code which adds `-A` to any string. Why did you expect to get the latter result?

Comment: So instead of -A how can I add just A to the string without hardcoding?

Comment: Where should the `A` come from if not by hardcoding?

Comment: So if the Station value is Shelves I just want it to print out ShelvesA instead

Comment: Did you try writing some sort of loop, including an `if` statement like `if value == 'Shelves'`, and using string concatenation, like `value + '-A'`?

Answer (score 0):

In my answer there are a few assumptions and changes in order to work. With not hardcoded you probably mean that the key value can change, right? I changed the b_dict values to empty lists in order to add all stores, sites etc. later on. Here is my solution. Really hope this is what you are looking for, because it was hard to understand your question.

```
a_dict = {'A': [['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate'], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']],'B': [['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate'], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]}
b_dict = {'Site':[], 'Store':[], 'Station':[]}



a_dict = [(x[0], x[1] ,x[2]+"-"+k) for k, v in a_dict.items() for x in v]

for obj in a_dict:
    for i, key in enumerate(b_dict.keys()):
        b_dict[key] += [obj[i]]

print(a_dict)
# [('LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate-A'), ('Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf-A'), ('Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves-A'), ('SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate-B'), ('Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf-B'), ('Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves-B')]

print(b_dict)
# {'Site': ['LA', 'Hollywood', 'Compton', 'SAC', 'Townsland', 'Compton'], 'Store': ['Sallys', 'Tonys', 'Sally', 'Sallys', 'Tonys', 'Tiffanys'], 'Station': ['Associate-A', 'Shelf-A', 'Shelves-A', 'Associate-B', 'Shelf-B', 'Shelves-B']}
```